# extending javascript and qweb template in Odoo 15?

Tags: odoo-15

I am trying to tweak the odoo wysiwyg web_editor in Odoo 15, just adding a few font sizes as an example. But it does not seem to work.

What i have tried: I created a module to isolate the problem:

https://github.com/jwaes/jt_webeditor_extras

Manifest:

```
    'assets' : {
    'web.assets_qweb': [
        'jt_webeditor_extras/static/src/xml/editor.xml',
    ],        
    'website.assets_wysiwyg': [
        'jt_webeditor_extras/static/src/js/editor.js',
    ],
```

xml:

```
<!-- fiddling with https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/web_editor/static/src/xml/editor.xml -->
<t t-extend="web_editor.toolbar">
    <t t-jquery="#font-size ul li:nth-child(7)" t-operation="after">
        <li>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-call="setFontSize" data-arg1="16px">16</a>
        </li>
    </t>
    <t t-jquery="#font-size ul" t-operation="append">
        <li>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-call="setFontSize" data-arg1="99px">99</a>
        </li>
    </t>
    <!-- perhaps my jquery was wrong... so trying with a drastic one -->
    <t t-jquery="#font" t-operation="replace" />

</t>
```

js:

```
odoo.define('jt_webeditor_extras.toolbar_extras', function (require) {
    'use strict';

    const weToolbar = require('web_editor.toolbar');

    weToolbar.include({
        xmlDependencies: (weToolbar.prototype.xmlDependencies || []).concat(
            ['/jt_webeditor_extras/static/src/xml/editor.xml']),
    });

    console.log(weToolbar.prototype.xmlDependencies);

});
```

The javascript console message was logged. so it was loaded.
There is a http call to the template xml from the frontend.
But the resulting UI is not altered.

Any idea what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the [odoo](https://github.com/jwaes/jt_webeditor_extras/blob/main/static/src/xml/editor.xml#L2) tag and add `web_editor` to module `depends` entry.

Comment: Thank you soo much ! That odoo tag ... it is something I really look over.